# How to clear a cart's attributes in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

Previously when I visited `/cart/clear` or did the below, it cleared my cart, and it's attributes. Now when I do either of those things, it clears the products, but the cart attributes are persisting. I'm not sure if this is a recent change or a Shopify bug?

Any idea how to clear the cart's attributes?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/cart/clear.js',
  success: function(){
    alert('You cleared the cart!');
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way to delete them all by doing this, which seems overly complicated, but it works.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/cart.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) { 
        var nullHash = {};
        for ([key, value] of Object.entries(resp.attributes)) {    
            nullHash[key] = null;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/cart/update.js',
            data: {attributes:nullHash},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
});
```

Or if you want to delete them by name, you can do this:

```
var nullHash = {
    'someAtt1': null,
    'someAtt2': null,
    'someAtt3': null
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/cart/update.js',
    data: {attributes:nullHash},
    dataType: 'json'
});
```